# require_once php 7

Tags: php

Здраствуйте. Написал CMS. Загрузил на сервер(PHP5.4), все работало нормально. Надо было php 7.0.32,переключил и начались проблемы. все скрипты после require_once
не срабатывают.
Что самое странное на денвере с php7.0.10 все хорошо работает. Помогите разобратьсяю

```
<?php
/**
 * Main Page Controller
 */
class MainController
{
    public function actionIndex($locale=''){
        echo phpversion()."<br>";
        echo fileowner(ROOT . '/views/category/index.php');
        $m_cat_list = Category::getCategoriesList($locale);
        $serv_data = Services::getServicesData($locale);
        //$title = Locale::get_dict('main',$locale);
        require_once (ROOT . '/views/category/index.php');
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: проверяйте права, путь, смотрите логи

Comment: что такое `ROOT` и где оно определено? начните с просмотра логов. зы: инклудить файлы посреди методов, как-то дурно выглядит.

Comment: define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); в index.php

Comment: И влоге все чисто